# Difference between java ' assert 'and ' if () {} else exit;'

Tags: java, assert

what is the difference between java `assert`  and  `if () {}  else exit;`?

can i just use `if () {} else exit` instead of `assert` ?

Comment: Have you tried reading documentation on `assert` and what it does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit of google maybe ?

" The main thing you should keep in mind is that the if-else statement should be used for program flow control and the assert keyword should only be used for testing purposes. You should never use asserts to actually perform any operation required for your application to work properly.
According to Sun's official Java documentation: "Each assertion contains a boolean expression that you believe will be true when the assertion executes." "

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_assert_keyword_and_if_keyword_in_java#ixzz1v2GGfAhq

Comment: ' int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);'
 ' assert(ptr);'
  '...'
'

Comment: Put your code in the code tag so I can see it better. It depends if you want to make a test. If you don't want to separate your tests from your actual code, use a if-else exit. Assertions are for testing purposes only ^^

Comment: It really depend on what you want to do. If you want to make some tests (which you could disable later) use assert. But if you want to do the same with `if else exit` statement you will have to add a variable to disable it and it will be much more complicated. Though if it is a part of your programm and you intend to leave it here, use a `if else exit` statement. As I said, assertions are for testing only.

Comment: I hate answers that say "just google it". Like, I did. That's why I'm here.

Answer (score 3):

you could, assert is specifically designed to assert some part of code,

assert will throw `AssertionError` if it fails to assert

---

**Also See**

- [`assert` reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html)

Answer (score 3):

I can just ignore the assertion

```
class A{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    assert false;
  System.out.println("hi");
}
}
```

This code will print hi by default

```
$ java -cp . A
hi
$ java -ea -cp . A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at A.main(A.java:6)
```

Answer (score 3):

> can I just use `if () {} else exit` instead of `assert` ?

Yes you could, but ...

- you wouldn't be able to turn of the test unless you made the condition depend on an extra flag (which makes it more complicated, etc),
- you wouldn't get a chance to perform tidy-up in any enclosing `finally` block,
- it would be more complicated to log the cause of the problem than if an `AssertionError` (or any other exception) was thrown, and
- if your code needed to be reused (as-is) in another application, your calls to `exit` could be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

if-else is for controlling the flow of your program. assert must not be used for this! Asserts are just for having "checkpoints" in your code to check conditions which "should always" match.

Asserts can be turned on or off when running a program so that you could enable the asserts on your development machine/integration environment and disable them in the released version.

Answer (score 2):

The assert keyword will only trigger an exception when you enable the assertions with `-ea` on the command line. The if/else will always execute. On top of that the assert keyword allows to write less verbose code. Compare:

```
assert parameter != null;
```

to:

```
if( parameter != null )
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Sure the assert allows you to write less verbose code, but you can still write `if (prm == null) throw new Exception(...);`. The assertions are just not made for that purpose, they are made so that when putting your program into production no useless tests are made (because your assertions are always supposed to be valid). Hence, they are removed from the production package.

Answer (score 1):

Asserts are ignored unless the -ea param is passed:

java -ea myjar.jar

That way, you can use them when you are testing your application, but ignore them at other times.